# In Persistent (Haskell), how can I insert a record only if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: haskell, haskell-persistent

I'm a Haskell beginner, so apologies in advance!

I've been following [the Persistent tutorial here](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent).

I have a data model with a uniqueness constraint:

```
Book
    gutId Int
    UniqueGutId gutId
    ...
    author [AuthorId]
    ... 
Author
    gutId Int
    UniqueAuthorGutId gutId
    ...
```

And when I go to `insert` a record using this:

```
  runSqlite "test.db" $ do
    runMigration migrateAll

    -- FIXME: This won't work if there's an author that's already in the database.
    authorIds <- mapM insert authors
```

It won't work if the record is already in the database. (It'll just return an exception.) I can do this instead:

```
authorIds <- mapM insertUnique authors
```

But the problem is, I need to use `authorIds` to update `Book` records later. So I'm just wondering if anyone knows of an easy way to insert a record if it doesn't exist, and return the new key, or get the record key if it already exists, so that I have an array of keys either way. [The full code at this point is up here.](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/corpus-db/blob/f3f051ce2a76d803f05fd8d99e1d6989ca9d3206/src/Main.hs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to perform both actions you mentioned yourself:

```
authorIds <- forM authors $ \a -> do
    res <- insertUnique a
    case res of
        Just key -> return key
        _ -> fromJust <$> getBy (authorGutId a)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
authorIds <- mapM (fmap (either entityKey id) . insertBy) authors

insertBy :: _ => -- some constraints
            record -> -- given some record, try to insert it
            _ ( -- in some monad
               Either (Entity record) (Key record)
               -- if found: Left existing
               -- otherwise: Right newKey
              )
Data.Either.either :: (l -> o) -> (r -> o) -> Either l r -> o
-- eliminator for Either
-- purpose and implementation completely determined by type
```

We use `insertBy` to try to insert the record. `fmap` drills underneath the monad, and `either entityKey id` extracts the `Key`.